# how will i rename an image file which i have taken as input throuch the textbox using the C# code

Tags: c#

how will i rename an imge file which i have taken as input throuch the textbox using the C# code

Comment: @vinay - welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please provide more information - it is very unclear from your quesion what technology you are using. Is is winforms, webforms, WPF, something else?

Comment: @vinay: To increase your chances of getting a useful reply do take care to tag your questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should give more context here, but:

- The type of file is probably irrelevant
- How you've received the filename is probably irrelevant
- The type of application may very well be relevant - is this a client app, a web app, what?
- [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) is probably what you're after.